# How to resize a Shell child window

Tags: java, resize, swt, childwindow

I have a child window, containing a form, Labels, Combos, Buttons aligned in a line, line by line. Form is not finite. There is a button for adding extra line of input fields. It *sort of works for the moment*... Problem is when the new line is added the child window size remains the same, however I want it to resize automatically.

child window is a standard SWT shell

```
Shell ConstantEditWindow = new Shell(parent);
```

I hava a button with sth like this:

```
addDesc.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            populateConstantMain(tariffConstantsOfType, descComp, descCompLayout, true);

            ConstantEditWindow.layout();

        }
    });
```

but id doesnt work :/ the child window wont resize ;(

Comment: Does the SWT `Shell` class provide a `repack()` method or something similar in spirit?

Comment: no ;( there is only .redraw() but it does not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html

And the api: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2Fpackage-summary.html

- .layout() layouts the children of a control
- pack() causes the receiver to be resized to it's preferred size.

Also convention has it that constant name in java should be ALL_IN_CAPITAL.

Comment: Thank you :) I managed to solve the problem by encapsulating my Texts, Combos, etc in ScrolledComposite :)